# sorting in java linked list

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I tried to implement linked list in java. I am trying to sort it.

The Program is as follows

```
class Link{
int data1;
String data2;
Link nextLink;

Link(int d1, String d2){
    data1=d1;
    data2=d2;
    nextLink=null;
}

void printLink(){
    System.out.println("{"+data1+", "+data2+"}");
}
}

class LinkList{
Link first;

LinkList(){
    first=null;
}

void insert(int d1, String d2){
    Link list=new Link(d1,d2);
    list.nextLink=first;
    first=list;
}

void printList(){
    Link currentLink=first;
    while(currentLink!=null){
        currentLink.printLink();
        currentLink=currentLink.nextLink;
    }
}
}

public class men{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkList l1= new LinkList();
        l1.insert(10,"ABC");
        l1.insert(20,"DEF");
        l1.printList();
    }
}
```

I want to Sort it by `data1` element.

Comment: why not use array list in this regard it is same as what you implement and there is sort method directly or use can use iterator to sort array list hope my explanation helps

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is to start with a new empty list that will become the sorted list. Remove nodes from the original list then insert then in order into the new list.

The fastest method is a variation of bottom up merge sort, using a small (26 to 32) array of references (pointers) to the first nodes of sorted lists, where array[i] is either 0 (null) or points to a list with 2 to the power i nodes in it. All nodes from the original list are merged into the array one at a time, then the array is merged to form a single sorted list. In this Wiki article, the merge() function merges two already sorted lists, and handles the case where one or both lists are empty to simplify the main code:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Answer (score 0):

I am late,but here is the implementation in java. hope it helps.

```
 class men{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        LinkList l1= new LinkList();
        l1.insert(10,"ABC");
        l1.insert(20,"DEF");
        l1.insert(30, "GHI");
        l1.insert(40, "JKL");
        l1.insert(5, "hhh");
        l1.printList();
        mergesort(l1);
        System.out.println("After sorting: ");
        l1.printList();
    }

    private static void mergesort(LinkList l1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Link curr=l1.first;

        if(l1.first!=null && l1.first.nextLink != null){
            Link middle= getMiddle(l1);

            if(middle == l1.first){
                //only two elements in the listt.just swap
                if(middle.data1>middle.nextLink.data1){

                    l1.first=l1.first.nextLink;
                    l1.first.nextLink=middle;
                    middle.nextLink=null;
                    //l1.printList();
                }
            }else{
                LinkList left=new LinkList();
                LinkList right=new LinkList();
                left.first=l1.first;
                right.first=middle.nextLink;
                middle.nextLink=null;

                mergesort(left);
                mergesort(right);

                Link cur_left=left.first;
                Link cur_right=right.first;
                l1.first=null;
                Link last=null;
                while(true){
                    if((cur_left !=null) && (cur_right !=null)){
                         if (cur_left.data1>cur_right.data1){
                             last=l1.insertAtLast(cur_right.data1, cur_right.data2, last);
                             cur_right=cur_right.nextLink;

                         }else{
                             last=l1.insertAtLast(cur_left.data1, cur_left.data2, last);
                             cur_left=cur_left.nextLink;
                         }
                    }else if(cur_left !=null){
                        last=l1.insertAtLast(cur_left.data1, cur_left.data2, last);
                        cur_left=cur_left.nextLink;
                    }else if(cur_right !=null){
                        last=l1.insertAtLast(cur_right.data1, cur_right.data2, last);
                        cur_right=cur_right.nextLink;
                    }else break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Link getMiddle(LinkList l1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(l1.first== null){return l1.first;}
        Link slow,fast;
        slow=fast=l1.first;
        while(fast.nextLink !=null && fast.nextLink.nextLink !=null){
            slow=slow.nextLink;
            fast=fast.nextLink.nextLink;
        }
        return slow;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the insertAtLast method in LinkList class ,so that the node gets inserted at last.                                                                                                   Link insertAtLast(int d1,String d2,Link last){
 Link toAppend=new Link(d1,d2);
 if(last==null)first=toAppend;
 else last.nextLink=toAppend;
 return toAppend;
}